# java : how to handle the design when template methods throw exception when overrided method not throw

Tags: java

when coding. try to solve the puzzle:

how to design the class/methods when InputStreamDigestComputor throw IOException?

It seems we can't use this degisn structure due to the template method throw exception but overrided method not throw it. but if change the overrided method to throw it, will cause other subclass both throw it.
So can any good suggestion for this case?

```
abstract class DigestComputor{


    String compute(DigestAlgorithm algorithm){
        MessageDigest instance;
        try {
            instance = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm.toString());
            updateMessageDigest(instance);

            return hex(instance.digest());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    abstract void updateMessageDigest(MessageDigest instance);

}

class ByteBufferDigestComputor extends DigestComputor{

    private final ByteBuffer byteBuffer;

    public ByteBufferDigestComputor(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
        super();
        this.byteBuffer = byteBuffer;
    }

    @Override
    void updateMessageDigest(MessageDigest instance) {
        instance.update(byteBuffer);

    }

}

class InputStreamDigestComputor extends DigestComputor{


               // this place has error. due to exception. if I change the overrided method to throw it. evey caller will handle the exception. but 
    @Override
    void updateMessageDigest(MessageDigest instance) {
        throw new IOException();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are schizophrenic.

You've got to decide whether the `DigestComputor.updateMessageDigest` method can, or can not throw `IOException`.  If you want that to be possible, then you must add it to the signature *in the base class*.  That is the only way to force the caller to do something about an `IOException`.  But the downside is that you also force callers of the other subclasses to handle the `IOException` ... which won't occur.

You cannot create a method override that throws checked exceptions that the overridden method does not.  That would break subtype substitutability, and Java doesn't allow it.

It it like a fork in the road.  You have to decide to go one way or the other.  You can't go both ways at the same time.

---

However there is a compromise (sort of):

```
public abstract class Base {
    public abstract void method() throws IOException;
}

public class A extends Base {
    public void method() throws IOException {
        //
    }
}

public class B extends Base {
    public void method() {  // Doesn't throw!!!
        //
    }
}
```

Now, if the caller knows that it has an instance of `B` it can do something like this:

```
Base base = ...
B b = (B) base;
b.method();  // No need to catch or propagate IOException
```

(IIRC, the ability to do this ... i.e. to reduce the exceptions thrown in an overriding method ... was added in Java 1.5.)

Comment: try {
   return new InputStreamDigestComputor(bufferedInputStream, algorithm)
     .compute();
  } catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {
   if (runtimeException.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
    throw (IOException) runtimeException.getCause();
   } else
    throw runtimeException;
  } finally {
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
  }

Comment: I choose this plan. 3ks, I think your words are right. I can't get both ways at the sametime.

Comment: your way is workable too. but I think force convert isn't nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: @jiafu - the "force convert" (type cast) approach is only to make life easier for the caller that knows that it is dealing with a `B`.  The alternative is to catch the exception.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your super class is not meant to throw an exception.

This is a case where your subclass is thus throwing an exception which is not expected by the overlying software architecture.  Thus you can :

1. update all subclasses to throw exceptions.
2. wrap the entire Digestor class framework  in a new class system.
3. (simplest) maintain the current code and simply wrap any exceptions you wish to throw in a RuntimeException.

RuntimeExceptions are the idiomatic way to throw exceptions in java which are not checked by the compiler or by method signatures, which occur somewhat unexpectedly.

Comment: 1) I think I can't do it. Due to that other sub-classes no need to throw IOException; 2) I can't catch your mean, can you give code sample.3)I can't do it too. Due to that I want caller know IOException, it can catch it. if throw runtimeException it mean no necessary to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else suggested, the simplest thing to do would be to simple wrap the real exception in a runtime exception.  As a result, you don't have to declare the exception in your throws clause.  If you're ambitious enough you can make your own subclass of RuntimeException and catch it at a higher level (this is what hibernate does, it catches all SQLExceptions thrown and wraps them in some subclass of DataAccessException which is a runtime exception).